# Angular 2 - Hide Panel with table when table is empty

Tags: angular, ngfor

I have an *ngFor that creates panels that hold tables.  The tables have an *ngFor that create `<td>`for each item in a data set.

On occasion the table will have null rows.  Is there a smart way to use Angular to hide the panel with the table has no children?  I can probably use jQuery to check for children on load, but I feel like there should be a more intuitive answer using Angular *ngFor.

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-6 cell-box" *ngFor="let siteGroup of sqlData | FilterData:[currentDate, selectedGroup] | UniqueValue:['Site']">

                <!-- SD Data -->
                <div class="panel panel-midblue">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <span>{{selectedGroup}} - {{siteGroup}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                        <table class="exportTable table table-hover table-condensed">
                            <thead>
                                <th>Metric Name</th>
                                <th>Daily&emsp;&emsp;&emsp;</th>
                                <th>Week to Date</th>
                                <th>Month to Date</th>
                                <th>Year to Date</th>
                            </thead>
                            <tr *ngFor="let item of sqlData | FilterData:[currentDate, selectedGroup, siteGroup, selectedType] | OrderBy:['MetricName',['Volume','TSF', 'ASA','AHT', 'ACW', 'ABAN', 'FCR']]" [attr.goalvalue]="item.DayMetGoal">
                                <td>{{item.MetricName}}</td>
                                <td class="cursor-hand" [attr.goalvalue]="item.DayMetGoal" (click)="ModalPopUp($event, item)">{{item.DayMetricValue | FormatMetric:item.MetricName }}</td>
                                <td class="cursor-hand" [attr.goalvalue]="item.WTDMetGoal" (click)="ModalPopUp($event, item)">{{item.WTDMetricValue | FormatMetric:item.MetricName }}</td>
                                <td class="cursor-hand" [attr.goalvalue]="item.MTDMetGoal" (click)="ModalPopUp($event, item)">{{item.MTDMetricValue | FormatMetric:item.MetricName }}</td>
                                <td class="cursor-hand" [attr.goalvalue]="item.YTDMetGoal" (click)="ModalPopUp($event, item)">{{item.YTDMetricValue | FormatMetric:item.MetricName }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <h5 class="text-muted"></h5>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Hidden]

```
<h3 [hidden]="!favoriteHero">
  Your favorite hero is: {{favoriteHero}}
</h3>
```

See angular documentation:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/a1-a2-quick-reference.html#!#ng-show

Comment: I appreciate you pointing out the method used to hide in Angular 2. Based on the provided code, how would I set a variable that I could use to check against.  I basically need to say, if 'item' has no value then hide the parent panel.

Comment: @Tekk_Know is sqlData an array of objects? If so you can do [hidden]="sqlData.length == 0"

Comment: sqlData is indeed an array of objects.  Do you know if doing sqlData.length will do the length after the filter pipes are applied?

Comment: @Tekk_Know Honesty, I'm not sure I haven't done that before. My assumption is that doesn't. Give it a try?